# Difference Between WAF attached CloudFront and Simple CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I recently set up a Web Application Firewall (WAF) for my web application, which is being served via CloudFront. To assess its impact, I conducted load testing using JMeter for both scenarios: with WAF enabled and without WAF. However, my observations didn't show any noticeable difference in the website traffic between the two configurations.

I now seek confirmation on whether a WAF will indeed affect website traffic or if it will remain unaffected and similar to the normal traffic flow.

Answer (score 1):

The WAF is there to block unwanted traffic with its rules and engines. The Cloudfront behind the WAF, and the Cloudfront without the WAF, are both the same Cloudfront and will respond the same to a request which arrives.

What rules did you enable in WAF? You can enable statistics on the number of blocks by WAF - see if that is responding.

What is your website origin? If you just did a simple test with S3, then the max load is virtually unlimited ($$$) and you'd be unlikely to hit that.

There's some things you can do to deliberately trigger WAF like try to access 'known' naughty urls etc.

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes I did it for testing only, I just need to check the request difference which is made because of WAF, as i have used jmeter all request were allowed , none of them were blocked.

So just need to confirm if it good request then there will be no response delay due WAF?


Regarding rules, I have used AWS free WAF rules (No custom rules were used).